# Regex ignore HTML comments

Tags: html, c++, regex

I need to filter links and images from html pages with c++ and regex and I came up with this phrase:

```
<\s*(a.*?href|img.*?src)\s*=\s*\"(.*?)\".*?\s*>
```

unfortunately this will also find links and images within comments which it shouldn't. I tried some negative look-aheads without success.

Comment: please read this once: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2815219

Comment: I need to extract all links and images from websites for a webcrawler project for my university.
<\s*(a.*?href|img.*?src)\s*=\s*\"(.*?)\".*?\s*>  extracts all links and images but we shouldnt get those within comments.

For example the this regex will find
<a href="testlink1"> which it should
as well as <!-- <a href="testlink2"> --> which it shouldn't

Comment: Don't use regex for that. Use a proper HTML parser.

Comment: unfortunately we are not allowed to use a HTML parser

Comment: Why can you not use an HTML parser?

Comment: That's an insane requirement.  Parsing general HTML is not a suitable job for a regex.  My suggestion i is to use a regex to remove HTML comments and CDATA sections and then search - but I'm sure that won't handle all the cases.  Note that links can be surrounded by single quotes as well as double.  I'm sure I've forgotten some other gotchas

Comment: @Casimir: possibly, though academic institutions are rather known for placing entirely unrealistic or daft limitations on assignments, such that they become rather poor examples of how to best solve the problem `:o)`.

Comment: @halfer: there's indeed a lot of pedagogical wares in books/tutorials and other, that choose html for training ground (it's clearly due to a lack of imagination.). It's sad because there's a lot of *real life* and more useful possible examples. But it isn't only a regex problem, think about oop or database tutorials with unrealistic example about cars with number of doors, colors, speed... Authors such lords speak to the peasants of the Middle Ages.

Answer (score 0):

There's no reason to do everything at once. Also, you didn't say what environment/editor/programming language, so I picked my favorite, C#.

1. Remove all comments:

using

```
var s1 = source.Replace("<!--.*?-->", "");
```

2. Extract links with your existing regex:

using

```
var s2 = Regex.Matches(s1, "<\\s*(a.*?href|img.*?src)\\s*=\\s*\"(.*?)\".*?\\s*> ");
```